# UnrealEngine Create parameteric shapes by using scripting (C++)

Tags: unreal-engine4, unrealscript, unreal-engine5

I am completely new to UnrealEngine.
My aim is to read JSON data and recreate shapes in UE.
I want to do it through scripting (not by using blueprints).
how can I create 3D shapes by using scripts in UE?
Shapes include cube, curves, polygons and holes.

here is a sample screenshot of my required output.

[image]

Comment: Unreal script is now longer in use. You can find bindings for other scripting languages online but nothing official. Unreal has a class  called UProceduralMeshComponent which can be used to create meshes programmatically, although you'd need to write or find something to parse json data for it.

Comment: Let me change my question then, is it possible to achieve same output by using blueprints? 
I just want Cubes, Polygons, Curves (all with or without holes).